# web2py scheduler problem with name 'emailNotification' not found in scheduler's environment

Tags: python, scheduler, web2py

I am new for web2py
I have 2 web2py applications with difference database. They are in same web2py environment.
One application is using PostgreSQL for scheduler to send email notification.
The scheduler is started by python `web2py.py -K notification -D 0`
Then I use RESTful API to call `scheduler.queue_task(emailnotification,timeout=60,period=300, repeats=0)`
But I get the error

```
2020-05-15 16:20:08,805 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 __init__ - 158 DEBUG -    traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/web2py/gluon/scheduler.py", line 304, in executor
    "name '%s' not found in scheduler's environment" % f)
NameError: name 'emailNotification' not found in scheduler's environment <thread._local object at 0x28aecb0> None

2020-05-15 16:20:08,818 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 async - 388 DEBUG -  partial output: "2020-05-15 16:20:08,799 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 define_tables - 593 DEBUG - defining tables (migrate=False)
2020-05-15 16:20:08,804 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 __init__ - 156 DEBUG -     new task report: FAILED
2020-05-15 16:20:08,805 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 __init__ - 158 DEBUG -    traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/web2py/gluon/scheduler.py", line 304, in executor
    "name '%s' not found in scheduler's environment" % f)
NameError: name 'emailNotification' not found in scheduler's environment <thread._local object at 0x28aecb0> None

"
2020-05-15 16:20:08,819 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 async - 414 DEBUG -   task completed or failed
2020-05-15 16:20:08,821 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 report_task - 893 DEBUG -  recording task report in db (FAILED)
2020-05-15 16:20:08,831 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 report_task - 932 INFO - task completed (FAILED)
2020-05-15 16:20:08,833 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 loop - 711 DEBUG - looping...
2020-05-15 16:20:08,838 - web2py.scheduler.local#3573 pop_task - 806 INFO - nothing to do
```

Do you have any idea for this?
But everything is OK, if `scheduler.queue_task(emailnotification,timeout=60,period=300, repeats=0)` has been put into `models/scheduler.py`

Comment: To which application is the API call made, and where exactly is the line `scheduler.queue_task(emailnotification,timeout=60,period=300, repeats=0)`? Presumably wherever that is, the `emailnotification` function has not been defined.

Comment: You mean I must defined emailnotification in models/scheduler.py?

Comment: Wherever `scheduler.queue_task(emailnotification,timeout=60,period=300, repeats=0)` is, `emailnotification` must be defined in that scope. For example, if called in a controller action, it could be defined in a model file, at the top level of the controller, or in the controller action itself, or it can be defined in a module and imported into any of those contexts.

Comment: I defined in controller, but get the error.
I moved it to models. No more error, but the emailnotification is not called as scheduler. The task is queued in scheduler_task db